# Dynamic header and side menu on MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to know how I can render a custom header (based on customerid) and a side menu (again, based on the customerid) + the main content.

On a search page, I have a list of customers. When I select a customer, it will take me to another page passing the id of that customer (/controller/action/id). However, on this new page, I would like to list customer details on the header (name, email, phone, etc), on the side menu, I would like to list the pets that this customer owns (dog1, cat2, etc) and on the main content I want to show details of the first pet on the list (side menu). The list of pets on the side menu should be links. For instance, the dog1 should be a link to its own details shown on the main content. Cat2 should be a link to show details on the main content, etc

I just don't know how I am going to pass the id to the header, side menu and content page, all at once!

I have seen the mvcMusicStore where we have a list of the genres on the left menu, but that does not change! In my case, the side menu should change according to the customer selected on the previous page! Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple choices. At first, you can use partial views:

```
in layout.cshtml [or in your usecase, search page]:
@Html.Partial(your-partial-view-name)
view: headerPartial.cshtml as an example:
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <span>Welcome</span> @User.Identity.Name
} else {
    <span>Login or Register</span>
}
```

This is the base logic. For your situation, you need something like this. But, if you have to load some data from for example database, I would suggest you using partial actions:

```
// in layout or search or any page you want to render partial views:
// For example you have a controller named MyPartials:
// Put this line where you want to render header:
@Html.Action("HeaderInfo", "MyPartials")
```

and action:

```
public class MyPartialsController : Controller {
    public ActionResult HeaderInfo() {
        var model = retrive header needed info from db
        return Partial(model);
    }
}
```

Let me know more about your problem in details, to suggest you a good solution

**UPDATE:**

Suppose:

Controller: `CustomerController`

Action: `SeletedCustomer`

Solution:

**1. Models:**

```
public class HeaderInfoModel { } // contains header data: name, email, phone, etc

public class SideInfoModel { } // dog1, cat2, etc

public class MainContentModel { } // holding main content data

// bringing all together
public class CustomerModel {
    public HeaderInfoModel HeaderInfo { get; set; }
    public SideInfoModel SideInfo { get; set; }
    public MainContentModel MainContent { get; set; }
}
```

**2. Controller**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller {
    public ActionResult SeletedCustomer(int id) {
        // use id and retrieve data you want, from db or anywhere else you want
        var model = new CustomerModel {
            HeaderInfo = SomeMethodToFetchHeaderData(id),
            SideInfo = SomeMethodToFetchSideData(id),
            MainContent = SomeMethodToFetchMainContent(id)
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**3. Main View: `Customer/SeletedCustomer.cshtml`**

```
@model CustomerModel 

<div id="header">
    <!-- put this where you want to render header -->
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HeaderInfo)
</div>

<div id="side">
    <!-- put this where you want to render side -->
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SideInfo)
</div>

<div id="main">
    <!-- put this where you want to render main content -->
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MainContent)
</div>
```

**4.** In your situation, using Display Templates is the easiest way. Create a folder named `DisplayTemplates` in one of these places: `~/Views/Customer/` or `~/Views/Shared`. It depends on where and how you want to use provided models. Again, in your case, I suggest create this: `~/Views/Customer/DisplayTemplates/`. And then add some views in that folder, which are described below:

**4.1.** Create `HeaderInfoModel.cshtml` in `~/Views/Customer/DisplayTemplates/`:

```
@model HeaderInfoModel

<div>
    implement your model presentation, I mean, show the data how you want
</div>
```

**4.2.** Create `SideInfoModel.cshtml` in `~/Views/Customer/DisplayTemplates/`:

```
@model SideInfoModel

<div>
    implement your model presentation, I mean, show the data how you want
</div>
```

**4.3.** Create `MainContentModel.cshtml` in `~/Views/Customer/DisplayTemplates/`:

```
@model MainContentModel

<div>
    implement your model presentation, I mean, show the data how you want
</div>
```

That is it. Done! With your situation, the best way I can suggest is that. However, you have multiple choices; It's completely depended on your project.

Comment: Hi Javad, thanks for answering! However, coming from a previous page where I have a list of customers, I will be passing an id (/controller/seletedcustomer/1003). This 1003 (id) is the only parameter I have to render a new page with three sections: header (the id 1003 is providing customer info on the header), and also the id relates to another table (foreign key) to bring the list of pets related to id 1003 on the side menu. I could pass the 1003 easily to the header, but how to pass to the header AND to the side menu at the same time? That is my point

Comment: Hi Javad, Thank you very much for your help! I could really advance in my project! I am now getting to pass all the data required to the view. I still have only one view, because I am thinking that I can render the header (customer) and sidebar(customer_pets) easily.

Comment: The problem is the maincontent, where I want to show details (weights and dates) of the selected dog from the side menu. I can bring all the weights however, I am getting all the weights together: for instance, Customer John has 3 dogs:dog1, dog2 and dog3. Each dog has its own history of weights (say three different weights on different dates). When bringing to the view, I am getting 9 weights (3 for each dog) all together. My database is: 1 customer has many dogs and each dog has many weights. (similar to customer with many orders and orders with many items).

Comment: I thought about calling a partial view for the maincontent, but I dont know how to call the controller for the main view (this controller receives the customer id) and also another controller for the partial view (this controller should have the pet id)! What do you think? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Well your question now, is different. Do you know about layouts? Did you any in your project? Also, another question: Do you want to show selected dogs details by ajax or doing this on server side? If you want, call me at [kavand.ds at gmail]. This is not a simple single question which I can answer here. You need a solution, not an answer. However, it seems you need a layout (or nested layout maybe, I don't know your project structure).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use some kind of partial view with condition like it shown below inside razor

```
if(this is correct page && CustomerID is available) { show the view }
```

You can pass parameters in ViewBag and use them inside your view.
If you are new to ASP.NET MVC, here are some cool tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc.

And here is tutorial of building partial views http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html for beginners.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Andrei, however those examples are for static headers and partial views. In my scenario, I need to pass an id to then render the header and side menu (both partial views??) according to a previous selection (id catch).